# Do CGWH spaces form an exponential ideal in Condensed Sets?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, condensed-mathematics

If $X$ is any condensed set and $Y$ is a compactly generated weak Hausdorff (CGWH) space (a.k.a. $k$-Hausdorff $k$-space), is $Y^X$ again a CGWH space? To be more precise, is $(\:\underline{Y}\,)^X$ in the image of the inclusion functor   $\,\underline{\,\cdot\,}:\mathsf{CGWH}\to \mathsf{Cond}(\mathsf{Set})$?

CGWH spaces form a reflective subcategory of condensed sets, so it would suffice to know whether the reflector $\mathsf{Cond}(\mathsf{Set})\to \mathsf{CGWH}$ preserves products (by *Day's reflection theorem*). Also, I think the answer to the question is "yes" if one replaces "CGWH spaces" by "quasi-separated condensed set" in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Having thought about this again, I think the following works.

<s>*(Warning: The argument below seems almost a bit too much on the side of generalities, so maybe someone with more experience can check whether there's not an issue hiding somewhere in the more sloppy parts of it.)*</s>

First, let $Y\in \mathsf{CGWH}$ and $K\in \mathsf{CompHaus}$. Then for all $L\in \mathsf{CompHaus}$:
\begin{align*}
    \underline{Y}^{\underline{K}}(L) &\cong \hom(\underline{L}, \underline{Y}^{\underline{K}}) \\
    &\cong \hom(\underline{L} \times \underline{K}, \underline{Y})\\
    &\cong \hom(\underline{L \times K}, \underline{Y}) \\
    &\cong \hom(L\times K, Y) \\
    &\cong \hom(L, Y^{K}) \\
    &\cong \hom(\underline{L}, \underline{Y^{K}})\\
    &\cong \underline{Y^{K}}(L).
\end{align*}
Hence, by the Yoneda lemma,
$$ \underline{Y}^{\underline{K}} \cong \underline{Y^{K}}$$
Now, every $X\in \mathsf{Cond}(\mathsf{Set})$ is the colimit of representables, written with an abuse of notation as follows,
$$ X \cong \mathrm{colim}_{K\to X} \underline{K}. $$
Therefore, if $Y\in \mathsf{CGWH}$ and $X\in \mathsf{Cond}(\mathsf{Set})$, then
\begin{align*}
    \underline{Y}^X &\cong \lim_{K\to X} \underline{Y}^{y(K)}\\ 
    &\cong \lim_{K\to X} \underline{Y^{K}} \\
    &\cong \underline{\lim_{K\to X} Y^{K}} \\
    &\cong \underline{Y^{\mathrm{colim}_{K\to X} K}} \\ 
    &\cong \underline{Y^{X(*)_{\mathrm{top}}}},
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 X \mapsto X(*)_{\mathrm{top}} := \mathrm{colim}_{K\to X} K, 
\end{align*}
is the left adjoint to the inclusion
$$ \underline{\cdot}: \mathsf{CGWH}\hookrightarrow \mathsf{Cond}(\mathsf{Set}), $$
and the colimit is taken in $\mathsf{CGWH}$. Therefore,
$$ \underline{Y}^X\cong \underline{Y^{X(*)_{\mathrm{top}}}}$$
and $\mathsf{CGWH}$ is indeed an exponential ideal in $\mathsf{Cond}(\mathsf{Set})$.

So it seems to make no difference whether I take my loop space $M^{\mathbb{S}}$, (or space of continuous functions $C(X)$, or whatever) in the more "classical" $\mathsf{CGWH}$ or in condensed sets, as long as the codomain is a CGWH space to begin with.

Comment: Nice! I think that works. The key is, I believe, that $\mathrm{CGWH}$ is in fact cartesian closed.

Comment: Great! Thanks for having a look.